# Custom ClickHandler class

Tags: gwt, interface, onclick, behavior

Is there a way to use the Clickhandler interface in GWT to build a custom subclass ? I need  ClickHandlers which should react on every second click. Achieving this behavior is not the problem for an implemented ClickHandler, but it would be great if don't have to add this code snippet  to each single ListBox element:

```
 boolean ingoreClick;
 lastSelection =  -1 ;
 listBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        if (!ignoreClick) {
            lastSelection = listBox.getSelectedIndex();
        }
        ignoreClick = !ignoreClick;     
    }
});
```

And now imagine that there is listbox1, listbox2 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is quite simple, answer by Manolo basically solves it, you only need to improve it a little bit:

```
public abstract class EvenClickHandler implements ClickHandler {
    private boolean eventClick= true;

    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        if (eventClick = !eventClick) {
          onEvenClick(event);
        }
    }


    protected abstract void onEvenClick(ClickEvent e);

}

...

listBox.addClickHandler(new EvenClickHandler (){

   protected void onEvenClick(ClickEvent e){
      lastSelection = listBox.getSelectedIndex();
   }

});
```

Comment: I changend the implementation of the custom handler to : 
        
         `ListBox lb;
   int lastSelection = -1;
          [...]
     if (lastSelection != lb.getSelectedIndex()) {
     
      onSecondClick(event);
      lastSelection = lb.getSelectedIndex();
     }`
lb is an instance of the listbox.So an event is only fired when the selected item of the listbox changed. The method above worked not correctly in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since `Clickhandler` is and interface you can implement whatever behavior in your customized class and use it wherever.

```java
  public class MyClickHancler implements ClickHandler {
    boolean first = false;
    String name;

    public MyClickHancler(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      if (first = !first) {
        System.out.println("First click on " + name);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Second click on " + name);
      }
    }
  }

  [...]

  widget1.addClickHandler(new MyClickHancler("widget-1"));
  widget2.addClickHandler(new MyClickHancler("widget-2"));
```

Comment: First thanks for your answer. I know that i could have implemented the interface this way, but this do not help me in this case. Normally i use the ClickHandler in a class like this  : 

`listBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(final ClickEvent event) {

//DOSTUFF    }
   }
  });`
And i need to handle the event in this class and not in a class which implements the click handler.

Comment: Sorry I missunderstood, but I keep not following, could you edit your question and paste the code you would like to work